# How to change the image size (column and row number) into the same size

Tags: envi

I’m using IDL program. But I have a question how to convert different row and column number (row/col) to the same size of column and row number of 36 time series NDVI images. These images grouped into three different column and row numbers. When I do the subset I used the same shapefile and Geographic Lat/long (WGS 84) projection for all of them. So I’d like to ask why col/row numbers of these images is different. Second how to correct their size into the same size (col/row number)?

Thanks for your help

Comment: So you have rectangular images and want to create square ones?

Answer (score 1):

gdal_translate.exe has an "-outsize" option that allows you to resize an image by defining the number of rows and columns in the output. This might help you fix your images if you can't figure out the issue in IDL.